# How to see if image drawn to form through graphic.drawimage has been clicked?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, drawimage

```
 ' Show game directions.
                    ShowGameObjective()

                    ' Press any cursor key to skip instructions.
                    If ButtonEasy = True Then
                           Gamemode = 1
                    ElseIf ButtonMedium = Clicked Then

                    End If
```

How do I see if an Image has been directly clicked? For example: I have three images (system.drawing.bitmap) on my graphics buffer; Easy, Medium, and Hard. In the code above if ButtonEasy image is clicked, it will set the integer of Gamemode to "1", and so on depending on what image is clicked.

I think this is actually really easy to do that it isn't documented on here or msdn.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: After thinking some more, would something like this work?

`Private Sub ButtonEasy_OnMouseClick ...
       GameMode=1
End Sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MouseClick event handler you can do something like:

```
Dim buttonRect = New Rectangle(50, 20, 100, 100)
If buttonRect.Contains(e.Location) Then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `MouseClick` event and check where `e.Location` is.

Comment: As in, on mouse click, check the position of the mouse click and cross reference it with the position of the images?

Comment: Or wouldnt like: Private Sub ButtonEasy_OnMouseClick ..., and then set the event to set GameMode=x

Comment: That depends what `ButtonEasy` is.

Comment: `Private Sub Control1_MouseClick(sender as Object, e as MouseEventArgs) _ 
     Handles Control1.MouseClick`    I found this code that seems a better way to do that, but how do I build this?